asyncio call_soon: mixing blocking and non blocking calls
I'm going through asyncio in Python, writing random snippets to teach myself how things work. I stumbled on a behavior that I do not understand and am hoping someone can shed some light on this. Let's say I have the following snippet
def blocking():
    logger.info("blocking called")
    time.sleep(3)
    logger.info("blocking done")
    pass

async def nonblocking():
    logger.info("nonblocking called")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    logger.info("nonblocking done")
    pass

async def amain():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.call_soon(blocking)
    await nonblocking()
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = timeit.default_timer()
    asyncio.run(amain())
    logger.info(f"elapsed {timeit.default_timer() - s}")

Then, which is surprising to me, this code takes in total 3 seconds to execute - as long as the blocking sleep. I'm not sure why this is not taking 4 seconds instead. To add to my confusion, if I change the await nonblocking() for an await asyncio.gather(nonblocking(), nonblocking(), nonblocking()) then suddenly the code does take 4 seconds. Obviously, the asyncio.gather call is expected to take 1 second, but I do not understand why I go from 3 to 4 seconds if I replace my single coro await by the gather await. Why does the above snippet take 3 seconds and not 4? What is call_soon actually doing in this case?
If I add another loop.call_soon(blocking) immediately after the current one, then first blocking and nonblocking are called, and after 3 seconds elapse and both are done, blocking is called for the second time. So I don't fully understand how call_soon works.

call_soon schedules the callback to be executed at next loop iteration. The first chance for a new iteration is at await asyncio.sleep where the current coroutine is suspended and scheduled to be continued after (at least) one second. blocking is executed now. After that the coroutine was paused long enough and is continued. The more complicated cases introduce tasks and decisions for the loop what to run next. As far as I know the decision mechanism is not specified.

With your original code the logging should look something like:
[__main__] - nonblocking called
[__main__] - blocking called
[__main__] - blocking done
[__main__] - nonblocking done
[__main__] - elapsed 3.0056726932525635

What is happening? You have a loop.call_soon(blocking) statement followed by await nonblocking(). But your blocking callback is not being invoked until after the call to nonblocking is made (as is shown in the log) and it goes into a wait with await asyncio.sleep(1). So when blocking is invoked afterwards and we do not get back to the nonblocking asyncio function until 3 seconds have elapsed by then the original call to asyncio.sleep(1) has been completed and the function returns immediately.
But what if we give the blocking function a change to run before nonblocking has a chance to do its call to await asycnio.sleep(1) as with the following slight change:
async def nonblocking():
    logger.info("nonblocking called")
    # Give blocking a chance to run:
    await asyncio.sleep(.00001)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    logger.info("nonblocking done")

Now you will see the elapsed time to be slightly more than 4 seconds. Or if instead of having await noblocking() we have instead await asyncio.gather(nonblocking()) (we do not need to call nonblocking 3 times; one suffices) you will also now see an elapsed time of 4 seconds because of the way the call to asyncio.gather works. That is, your blocking callback gets invoked before nonblocking is invoked, as your logging no doubt shows:
[__main__] - blocking called
[__main__] - blocking done
[__main__] - nonblocking called
[__main__] - nonblocking done
[__main__] - elapsed 4.020106077194214

That is, if you look at your logging messages carefully, then all mysteries are solved.

Thanks alot. I think what is still not clear to me is when the callback is invoked, and what causes it to be invoked. Why does it get invoked immediately on the await nonblocking() but not on the await asyncio.gather(nonblocking())? Docs say that call_soon schedules the task to be run at the next iteration of the event loop - so I guess it is not clear to me at what point a new iteration of the event loop starts and why.

I don't know if this will hep but Invoking await nonblocking() results in immediately calling nonblocking whereas  asyncio.gather(nonblocking()) results in a call to loop.create_task(nonblocking()) and so nonblocking is merely being scheduled to run giving the blocking callback a chance to run before nonblocking.
